# Errors installing gems locally - how can I install slacker offline?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to [install slacker](https://github.com/vassilvk/slacker/wiki/Installation) so I can do some SQL testing.  I've never used Ruby before.  I'm on Windows.  My dev box only has access to the Internet via a proxy and I have to nominate all URls in advance.

I I downloaded and ran `rubyinstaller-devkit-2.7.5-1-x64.exe` (because it requires Ruby 2.4/2.5+ and 2.7.X was recommended at the Ruby site) accepting all of the defaults.

When it got to MSYS2 I hit ENTER (MSYS2 base installation and MINGW development toolchain).

I got errors in the gpg section, e.g. (but not limited to)

```
==> Updating trust database...
gpg: marginals needed: 3  completes needed: 1  trust model: pgp
gpg: depth: 0  valid:   1  signed:   6  trust: 0-, 0q, 0n, 0m, 0f, 1u
gpg: depth: 1  valid:   6  signed:   6  trust: 0-, 0q, 0n, 6m, 0f, 0u
gpg: depth: 2  valid:   6  signed:   0  trust: 6-, 0q, 0n, 0m, 0f, 0u
gpg: next trustdb check due at 2022-03-03
gpg: error retrieving 'alexey.pawlow@gmail.com' via WKD: No name
gpg: error reading key: No name
gpg: refreshing 1 key from hkps://keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: keyserver refresh failed: No name
==> ERROR: Could not update key: F40D263ECA25678A
```

Later, it said

```
MSYS2 seems to be properly installed
```

I then got a whole bunch of warnings about things being `up to date -- skipping`.

Then, it said

```
Install MSYS2 and MINGW development toolchain succeeded
```

and the MSYS2 window went back to the installation menu, so I closed the window.

Then, as per the instructions on the slacker site, I tried:

```
gem install slacker
```

I got:

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'slacker' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - no such name (https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

I figured this was a proxy server issue and read around and discovered that if I downloaded the gems to a local folder, I could run the command from that folder and it should work.  So, I downloaded `slacker-1.0.24.gem` from https://rubygems.org/gems/, unblocked the file and tried the command from that folder.  I got a similar error to above for `tiny_tds`.  I repeated the process until I appeared to have all required gems:

```
bundler-1.17.3.gem
diff-lcs-1.5.0.gem
rspec-3.10.0.gem
rspec-core-3.10.1.gem
rspec-expectations-3.10.1.gem
rspec-mocks-3.10.2.gem
rspec-support-3.10.3.gem
ruby-odbc-0.99999.gem
slacker-1.0.24.gem
tiny_tds-2.1.5.gem
```

Finally, it looked like it was working for a few seconds and then I got a whole new bunch of errors.  Here are the first few - I can post the lot if it will help:

```
Temporarily enhancing PATH for MSYS/MINGW...
Installing required msys2 packages: mingw-w64-x86_64-freetds
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-x86_64-openssl-1.1.1.l-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.msys2.org : Could not resolve host: mirror.msys2.org
warning: too many errors from mirror.msys2.org, skipping for the remainder of this transaction
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-x86_64-freetds-1.2.6-2-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.msys2.org : Could not resolve host: mirror.msys2.org
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-x86_64-p11-kit-0.24.0-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.msys2.org : Could not resolve host: mirror.msys2.org
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-x86_64-ca-certificates-20210119-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.msys2.org : Could not resolve host: mirror.msys2.org
```

then after those, this:

```
warning: failed to retrieve some files
error: failed to commit transaction (invalid url for server)
pacman failed with the following output:
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (6) mingw-w64-x86_64-ca-certificates-20210119-1  mingw-w64-x86_64-libffi-3.3-4  mingw-w64-x86_64-libtasn1-4.18.0-1  mingw-w64-x86_64-openssl-1.1.1.l-1  mingw-w64-x86_64-p11-kit-0.24.0-1  mingw-w64-x86_64-freetds-1.2.6-2

Total Download Size:    6.24 MiB
Total Installed Size:  77.14 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n]
:: Retrieving packages...
 mingw-w64-x86_64-openssl-1.1.1.l-1-any downloading...
 mingw-w64-x86_64-freetds-1.2.6-2-any downloading...
 mingw-w64-x86_64-p11-kit-0.24.0-1-any downloading...
 mingw-w64-x86_64-ca-certificates-20210119-1-any downloading...
 mingw-w64-x86_64-libtasn1-4.18.0-1-any downloading...
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing slacker:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

And more.  There was also a reference to a log file which contained sections like this:

```
find_header: checking for sybfront.h... -------------------- no

"gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby27-x64/include/ruby-2.7.0/x64-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby27-x64/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby27-x64/include/ruby-2.7.0 -I. -I/opt/local/include -I/opt/local/include/freetds -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetds -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=1 -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -O3 -fno-fast-math -fstack-protector-strong conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby27-x64/lib -L/opt/local/lib -L/opt/local/lib/freetds -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib/freetds -L. -pipe -s -fstack-protector-strong  -m64   -lx64-msvcrt-ruby270  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
6: {
7:   return !!argv[argc];
8: }
/* end */
```

To my questions:

1. Is there any way to resolve this without getting the URLs added to the proxy list?  It's basically at least a week per change because of the hoops we have to jump through.
2. If I need to get the URLs added to the proxy list, is there a master list or URLs so I can do it once and be sure it will work?  I've tried Googling it but I just end up with help getting Ruby code to use proxys not the installer.

Comment: I would really recommend using WSL2 and installing Ubunto or whatever flavor of linux you prefer. While Ruby has gotten slightly better at windows compatibility almost all the tutorials assume you're using osx/linux and you'll spend more time being productive and less time banging your head against the wall.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  The host is already virtualised and there are some serious downsides to nested virtualisation.  Also, I'm not sure it's supported in our situation, or if the VM team would agree to it.  For those reasons, I'll have to keep this as a last resort.

Comment: The main determining factor should really be what OS you're actually going to be deploying to. If you're going to be deploying to IIS/Azure then you're stuck with the mess. If not you really should be developing on the same OS to avoid a bunch of headaches down the line.

Comment: I'm stuck with this mess.

Comment: I have answered question 1 myself. If anyone else can give me a definitive answer to part two, I will happily mark that as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have answered question 1 myself.  If anyone else can give me a definitive answer to part two, I will happily mark that as the answer.

I guessed that I needed to download and install the `mingw` packages that couldn't be downloaded somewhere.  I did a bit of trawling and found this article ([Offline installation of packages](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/offline_installation_of_packages))which gave me the pointers I needed.  I got these four files from https://repo.msys2.org/mingw/mingw64/:

```
mingw-w64-x86_64-freetds-1.2.6-2-any.pkg.tar.zst
mingw-w64-x86_64-libtasn1-4.18.0-1-any.pkg.tar.zst
mingw-w64-x86_64-openssl-1.1.1.l-1-any.pkg.tar.zst
mingw-w64-x86_64-p11-kit-0.24.0-1-any.pkg.tar.zst
```

And `mingw-w64-x86_64-ca-certificates-20210119-1-any.pkg.tar.zst` from https://ftp.acc.umu.se/mirror/msys2.org/mingw/mingw64/.

I copied them to: `C:\Ruby27-x64\msys64\home\myUserId\freetds` which is in my home dir in `msys`.  (From errors I got the first time, it looks like the folder name has to match the database name.)  Then I started `msys` by running: `C:\Ruby27-x64\msys64\msys2.exe`.

In `msys`, I ran:

```
cd freetds/
```

then, to create a repository database just for freetds:

```
$ repo-add freetds.db.tar.gz *.pkg.tar.zst
```

I got a bunch of messages telling me it was `==> Adding package 'ming...`

I needed to edit the pacman.conf file to point to my temp database, so I made a copy of the pacman.conf file:

```
cp /etc/pacman.conf /etc/pacman.conf.old
```

I edited `pacman.conf` in Notepad++, changing `SigLevel` to `= Never`, commenting out the other repositories, and adding this to the end:

```
[freetds]
Server = file:///home/myUserId/freetds
```

Then, I made `pacman` synchronise with the database I created:

```
pacman -Sy

:: Synchronizing package databases...
 freetds              1676.0   B  7.54 KiB/s 00:00 [#####################] 100%
```

I tried `gem install slacker` again but there was another missing package `"mingw-w64-x86_64-libffi`, so I downloaded `mingw-w64-x86_64-libffi-3.3-4-any.pkg.tar.zst` and put it in the same place, re-ran the `repo-add` command and `pacman Sy` and then `gem install slacker`.

This worked and I got `10 gems installed`.  I've run the test project documented in the slacker GitHub pages and it worked.